# is there anymistake in my code i'm trying to fetch api on react native chart kit

Tags: reactjs, react-native, fetch-api, react-native-chart-kit

i'm trying to fetch my json api on react native chart kit using async await but my code is giving error map is not defined..

here's error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

here my code react native android

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { LineChart } from 'react-native-chart-kit';

const Screen1 = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const response = await fetch('https://script.googleusercontent.com/macros/echo?user_content_key=4CmBJH-t4l8ttf8ZbxbCbmzvEbJH3Ia_ja0IZluqEYcfMGQbXbN4cQ4iZ42wKRZZIgmJqtzTWLTa0xF1lhksn1SA7CZrB2vTm5_BxDlH2jW0nuo2oDemN9CCS2h10ox_1xSncGQajx_ryfhECjZEnFUk1oS11HODC4kgVFcklP7bly7smBobZeLSs9YBkifDWjjSjPFy1arSlO4XMWHwy6rFUIhT1qAKQGwcfvSKEfWhfhmpWtCcBNz9Jw9Md8uu&lib=MwHLfleKugAQlVo-Cygvk5qOcTyEVBS6e');
      const result = await response.json();
      setData(response.data);
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const chartData = {
    labels: data.map(item => item.put),
    datasets: [
      {
        data: data.map(item => item.call),
      },
    ],
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <LineChart
        data={chartData}
        width={320} // from react-native
        height={220}
        yAxisLabel="$"
        yAxisSuffix="k"
        yAxisInterval={1} // optional, defaults to 1
        chartConfig={{
          backgroundColor: '#e26a00',
          backgroundGradientFrom: '#fb8c00',
          backgroundGradientTo: '#ffa726',
          decimalPlaces: 2, // optional, defaults to 2dp
          color: (opacity = 1) => `rgba(255, 255, 255, ${opacity})`,
          labelColor: (opacity = 1) => `rgba(255, 255, 255, ${opacity})`,
          style: {
            borderRadius: 16,
          },
          propsForDots: {
            r: '6',
            strokeWidth: '2',
            stroke: '#ffa726',
          },
        }}
        bezier
        style={{
          marginVertical: 8,
          borderRadius: 16,
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default Screen1;
```

please can someone tell me where i'm mistaken

Answer (score 0):

I think it because you are setting response.data `setData(response.data);` instead of `setData(result.data);` but when I look response data it should be something like this `setData(result.AlgoData)`

Comment: thats good but still code is not working...chart is not forming is there any else mistake

Comment: One of the reason might be is that your data is not in JSON format. Since you are using as item.put and item.call while you are setting your chartData, it is not object it is in array format. Try to organize your response data according to the `react-native-chart-kit` package requires.